# How to convert a Uint8ClampedArray array into a png image in node.js?

Tags: node.js, image

I am using this library to read png images, but in general

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pngjs2

if I have a Uint8ClampedArray, a width and height of the array, how can I convert that and save it as a png image in node.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same library to create a png image if the dimensions are known and the data is in the form of a Uint8ClampedArray. Example:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    PNG = require('pngjs2').PNG;

var img_width = 16;
var img_height = 16;
var img_data = Uint8ClampedArray.from([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 134, 133, 110, 6, 97, 137, 82, 249, 97, 142, 79, 255, 93, 142, 74, 255, 90, 140, 71, 255, 90, 142, 70, 255, 79, 129, 60, 250, 115, 134, 92, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 133, 152, 125, 15, 111, 151, 96, 255, 223, 255, 209, 255, 174, 253, 148, 255, 158, 249, 126, 255, 141, 249, 103, 255, 71, 145, 43, 255, 68, 143, 42, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 137, 158, 131, 20, 111, 153, 96, 255, 216, 255, 201, 255, 172, 247, 145, 255, 156, 244, 124, 255, 139, 242, 102, 255, 72, 145, 44, 255, 75, 144, 47, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 137, 158, 131, 25, 110, 154, 94, 255, 196, 252, 178, 255, 157, 242, 125, 255, 144, 239, 110, 255, 129, 237, 91, 255, 70, 145, 42, 255, 70, 142, 43, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 132, 153, 128, 30, 107, 155, 90, 255, 177, 245, 151, 255, 134, 233, 100, 255, 125, 230, 87, 255, 114, 229, 73, 255, 69, 146, 41, 255, 66, 140, 40, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 126, 154, 120, 55, 103, 155, 83, 255, 154, 236, 125, 255, 111, 223, 71, 255, 109, 222, 69, 255, 109, 225, 69, 255, 69, 146, 40, 255, 63, 133, 41, 44, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 116, 142, 107, 82, 100, 154, 79, 255, 145, 229, 114, 255, 103, 218, 62, 255, 105, 218, 65, 255, 106, 220, 66, 255, 69, 145, 39, 255, 67, 125, 49, 82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 71, 119, 56, 249, 126, 178, 106, 255, 122, 174, 104, 255, 128, 194, 105, 255, 140, 226, 109, 255, 105, 215, 65, 255, 103, 214, 63, 255, 104, 215, 63, 255, 84, 167, 53, 255, 78, 139, 54, 255, 78, 142, 54, 255, 71, 127, 50, 250, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31, 91, 8, 240, 63, 157, 29, 255, 134, 222, 103, 255, 153, 229, 124, 255, 166, 233, 140, 255, 110, 213, 73, 255, 100, 210, 61, 255, 100, 210, 61, 255, 125, 221, 91, 255, 124, 221, 89, 255, 78, 179, 43, 255, 54, 122, 29, 240, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 78, 7, 42, 39, 106, 14, 253, 60, 156, 26, 255, 120, 210, 88, 255, 127, 217, 96, 255, 119, 214, 85, 255, 96, 207, 56, 255, 98, 209, 59, 255, 95, 204, 56, 255, 70, 166, 37, 255, 57, 131, 30, 253, 48, 108, 24, 53, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 29, 87, 9, 42, 42, 107, 18, 249, 63, 160, 28, 255, 107, 201, 73, 255, 121, 212, 88, 255, 108, 210, 72, 255, 87, 194, 50, 255, 62, 153, 30, 255, 50, 118, 25, 249, 43, 103, 23, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 93, 13, 38, 46, 109, 22, 241, 68, 166, 32, 255, 99, 197, 63, 255, 89, 185, 55, 255, 54, 141, 24, 255, 44, 108, 20, 241, 36, 93, 19, 38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42, 97, 12, 26, 47, 110, 25, 230, 68, 162, 37, 255, 46, 127, 17, 255, 39, 98, 16, 230, 33, 89, 13, 26, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 93, 21, 16, 50, 112, 26, 223, 41, 101, 19, 225, 20, 72, 0, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
var img_png = new PNG({width: img_width, height: img_height})
img_png.data = Buffer.from(img_data);
img_png.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('tick.png'))
```